# Javascript getElementById() throwing Object not supported error

Tags: javascript

I read a html content from some other page and stored it i one variable. I need to get the value from newly stored variable.

Here is my code,

```
Var hValue="<div class='myclass'><h3 id='ct100_title'>This is title</h3><h3 id='ct100_Content'>So this is content of the page</h3></div>";
```

Here i need to get the title and content value. Is there any way?

Comment: `Var` is invalid. Where/how exactly is the error thrown? Where/how do you call the method? Your code example appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Couldn't you define `document.getElementById("ct_title").innerHTML` as a variable x and then your variable `x` will contain the title.

Comment: Is it okay for you using `jquery`

Comment: First append the html content to any element,then try to access it. Can you show how you are calling it, i cant see getElementById in your code

Comment: Until and unless you dont append that html content to any element it wont be treated as dom node its still a normal string

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
x.innerHTML = "<div class='myclass'><h3 id='ct100_title'>This is title</h3><h3 id='ct100_Content'>So this is content of the page</h3></div>";
var eles = x.getElementsByTagName('h3');
console.log(eles[0].textContent);
console.log(eles[1].textContent);
```

Comment: This should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like,

```
var elem  = document.createElement('div');
elem.style.display='none';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elem);
elem.innerHTML ="<div class='myclass'><h3 id='ct100_title'>This is title</h3><h3 id='ct100_Content'>So this is content of the page</h3></div>";
alert( "" + document.getElementById('ct100_title').innerHTML);
alert( "" + document.getElementById('ct100_Content').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score -1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LeP2j/)

Until and unless you dont append that html content to any element it wont be treated as dom node its still a normal string. However you can also use regex to find the title and content in string only because each time accessing dom is not a good idea.

```
var hValue="<div class='myclass'><h3 id='ct100_title'>This is title</h3><h3 id='ct100_Content'>So this is content of the page</h3></div>";

var parent = document.getElementById("MyTragetDiv"); // fictitious div to append the content
parent.innerHTML = hValue;

var titleNode = document.getElementById("ct100_title"); 
var title = (titleNode.innerText || titleNode.textContent);    // i will have title text

var contentNode = document.getElementById("ct100_Content"); 
var content= (contentNode.innerText || contentNode.textContent);  // i will have content text
```